# PHP "||" is returning the wrong value

Tags: php

I am making an upload script for a music-related thing i am building.
I check whether the file is an MP3 or an OGG, but even if it IS, php will return true on this and say that it isnt on either of these checks.
Here's some example code:

```
$ft = "mp3";
if($ft != "mp3" || $ft != "ogg") { echo "not an ogg / mp3"; }
```

What it returns:

```
not an ogg / mp3
```

If i am doing something wrong, i am more than glad to be crapped on by Stack Overflow this time, cuz at least i know i did something *stupidly* wrong.

Comment: You should do opposite if ft == mp3 || ft== oog. Because you're 1st condition return false as file is MP3 but send return true and hence print not an mp3/oog file

Comment: I'd suggest changing the title as the operator is working as expected

Comment: As pointed out in the answer, `&&` would be the correct operator. You could also use `!in_array($ft, ['mp3', 'ogg'])` -- that would be easier to maintain if you add more extensions.

Comment: @RaoDYC that would be the condition for a positive match on either of the two extensions, which should respond with "IS mp3 / ogg".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`||` operator means `or` so if one of the following conditions is true it will do the action of the condition , you need to change it to `&&` which means the both condition should be `true` to do the action